Como puedo añadir una imagen de logo a un archivo de Excel desde React?
Me pidieron que todos los archivos que se descarguen tienen que tener una hoja personalizada de excel en donde se incluye un logo de la empresa. El logo es una imagen en png, que ocupa desde la celda A1 hasta la J1. La aplicacion que desarrollo trae datos de una API y las muestra en columnas en la interfaz, hay un boton de descargar y este exporta los datos de esa api a un excel. Todo esto se maneja en el front. Estoy usando REACT.
He visto varios videos pero la mayoria llama a las imagenes desde la Api y en mi caso la tengo localmente. No se como añadir laimagen para que siempre aparezca en las descargar y asegurarme que el cliente tambien vaya a poderla descargar. la aplicacion se sube a un servidor y actualmente la desarrollo local
const ExcelJS = require('exceljs');
const path = require('path');

const exportToXLSX = async (excludedColumnIndexes) => {
    const productListExport = [];
    const headers = ["Nombre", "Descripcion", "ID"];
    productListExport.push(headers);
    productList.forEach(obj => {
        const values = Object.values(obj).slice(0); 
        productListExport.push(values);
    });
    productListExport.push(["", "", ""]);
    productListExport.push([`${getBitacora()}`, "", ""]); 

    const workbook = new ExcelJS.Workbook();
    const worksheet = workbook.addWorksheet('Plataforma');

    // Añadir los datos a la hoja de cálculo
    productListExport.forEach((row, index) => {
        worksheet.addRow(row, 'n');
    });

    // Añadir la imagen
    const logo = workbook.addImage({
        filename: path.resolve(__dirname, 'ruta/a/mi/logo.png'),
        extension: 'png',
    });

    worksheet.addImage(logo, {
        tl: { col: 0, row: 0 },
        br: { col: 9, row: 0 }
    });

    // Guardar el archivo
    await workbook.xlsx.writeFile('Plataforma.xlsx');
};

